# scroll event has some strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this type of problem.

I have a scroll event which is checking if I have reached end of the page and then it fetches data from the server and that part is working correctly.

Problem that I have is that on the older computers I have a problem of getting double items that are loaded when the scroll event happens.

What could I do to make this code work as it is working normally on the faster computers...

I tried to `delay()` the code inside the scroll event and the same thing is happening...

Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
    {
       $(".loader").show().delay(700).fadeOut();
       $.ajax({ ///more code });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loading = false;
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
    {
      if(!loading){
       loading = true;
       $(".loader").show().delay(700).fadeOut();
       $.ajax({ ///more code })
       .done(function(){
          loading = false;
       });
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: `.done()` I never thought of it :) this is great! So this is only triggered when ajax call is done, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
```

but this:

```
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height())
```

And use a var for the status and check it

Comment: why to use `if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height())`, I am normally triggering end of the page